# Why does LEGO Star Wars III: The Clone Wars have different ESRB ratings between the DS and 3DS?

Tags: version-differences, esrb, lego-star-wars-3-the-clone-wars

What's the deal regarding ESRB ratings of `LEGO Star Wars III: The Clone Wars` in the DS and 3DS formats?  I ask, because I need an explanation that can get this game past a picky mom of a <10 kid.

[The DS version shows as a "E" rating.](http://www.nintendo.com/games/detail/fKDeka-cXQq0Tys5QubWjx0GC9GnFLBz)

[The 3DS version shows an "E 10+" rating.](http://www.nintendo.com/games/detail/o6j0GxVzKxRe0kE4RQJq3Kc1uEhL_Dx2)

The links above both say "Cartoon Violence" and "Comic Mischief", and I can't imagine that there is any real difference.  I saw this game in a store, and I was certain that it said "Cartoon Violence" and "Crude Humor".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ESRB site lists summaries for the titles they rate. There are differences in the descriptions of the game for each platform ([3DS](http://www.esrb.org/ratings/synopsis.jsp?Certificate=30229),
[DS, PSP](http://www.esrb.org/ratings/synopsis.jsp?Certificate=30640),
[Windows PC, PlayStation 3, Xbox 360](http://www.esrb.org/ratings/synopsis.jsp?Certificate=30332),
[Wii](http://www.esrb.org/ratings/synopsis.jsp?Certificate=30500)); specifically, the 3DS version includes:

> Laser sounds, large explosions, and battle cries can be heard during
>   the sometimes frenetic combat;

while the DS version doesn't.